# Are $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\tilde{\mathbb{R}^n}$ Homeomorphic?

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

Let $\tilde{\mathbb{R}^n}$ be the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^\omega$ consisting of all sequences $x = (x_i)$ such that $x_i = 0$ for all $i > n$. I want to show this is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$. Consider $f: \tilde{\mathbb{R}^n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ defined by

$$f(x_1,...,x_n,0,...) = (x_1,...x_n)$$

It is easy to see that if $g : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \tilde{\mathbb{R}^n}$ is defined as $g(x_1,...,x_n) = (x_1,...,x_n,0,....)$, then $g \circ f$ and $f \circ g$ are the identity functions, thereby proving $g=f^{-1}$ and that $f$ is a bijection. Now, by the maps-to-products theorem, $f$ is continuous since $f(x) = (\pi_1(x),...,\pi_n(x))$ and each $\pi_i : \mathbb{R}^\omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ (projection map) is continuous (note, we are looking at the restriction of each $\pi_i$ to the subspace $\tilde{\mathbb{R}^n}$)

I want to say I can apply the same theorem to $f^{-1}$, but I am not sure if this is questionable. Letting $pr_i : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be the projection map and $\tilde{0} : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined as $\tilde{0}(x) =0$ , it seems that $f^{-1}(x) = (pr_1(x),....,pr_n(x),\tilde{0}(x),...)$, which ought to be continuous according to the theorem alluded to above, since each $pr_i$ is continuous and $\tilde{0}$ is continuous.

On second thought, I am not sure I used the theorem properly in either case. Does my proof seem correct?

EDIT: By the way, here is a statement of the maps-to-products theorem: Let $h : A \rightarrow \prod X_i$ be given by the equation $h(a) = (h_i(a))$, where $h_i : A \rightarrow X_i$ for each $i$. Let $\prod X_i$ have the product topology. Then $f$ is continuous if and only if each $f_i$ is continuous.

Comment: Your proof is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have written for $f$ is correct, but the proof for $g$ warrants more care. It suffices to show that  $g^{-1}(U)$ is open when

$$U=\{x\,:\,x_j\in V\},$$

for $j\in\mathbb N$ and $V\subseteq\mathbb R$ open. For $j>n$ this is trivial (why?). For $j\le n$, $g^{-1}(U)=\{y\in\mathbb R^n\,:\,y_j\in V\}$ which is of course open.

Comment: So, I cannot write $f^{-1}$ as I did and apply the theorem? Where exactly did it go wrong? I cannot see it.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with what you've done really, but you did not seem confident in your approach and so I offered a different one (which in my opinion illuminates why this is the case more clearly). If you understand the maps-to-products theorem well then this is an almost trivial application, and if you do not it can be helpful to re-prove it for specific examples (which is essentially what I do in my answer).